# CSS grid with minimum and maximum values

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have created grid using CSS grid as follows:

Example in: https://codepen.io/asdfaaaasdf/pen/wvYJzgJ

```css
.box {
  background: grey;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}


}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">One</div>
  <div class="box">Two</div>
  <div class="box">Three</div>
</div>
```

What I need is that, if the width of the screen shrinks, the items should moved to second row when the item size is less than the minimum size. Similarly, if the screen is expanded then item size should be increased until item size reaches maximum width.
How can I do that? Is it possible to add min-width and max-width or something similar to css grid?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems like you are looking for a box to get wrap as per the screen size. And it should get back in the row when screen have the enough width.

You were really close to the solution. I just added `max-width: 100%;` in `.box` class CSS.

Here is the solution https://codepen.io/abhijeetabnave/pen/eYPvBYa

```css
.box {
  background: grey;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: end;
}
.wrapper {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  justify-content: end;
}}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box">One</div>
   <div class="box">Two</div>
   <div class="box">Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @StaticName I have updated the code as per new changes by you, please have a look and if it resolves your problem please accept the answer